# function not being overridden in child class

Tags: python, inheritance

I have these two classes:

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, start_point, *args):
        self.vertices = []
        self.__make_vertices(start_point, *args)

    def __make_vertices(self, start_point, *args):
        print "Not Implemented: __make_vertices"

    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        return self.vertices.__getitem__(*args)

class Cube(Shape):
    def __init__(self, start_point, side_length):
        Shape.__init__(self, start_point, side_length)

    def __make_vertices(self, start_point, side_length):
        append = self.vertices.append
        start_point = Vector(*(start_point))
        i, j, k = side_length*I, side_length*J, side_length*K
        append(start_point)
        append(self.vertices[-1] - k)
        append(self.vertices[-1] - j)
        append(self.vertices[-1] + k)
        append(self.vertices[-1] - i)
        append(self.vertices[-1] - k)
        append(self.vertices[-1] + j)
        append(self.vertices[-1] + k)
        print self.vertices
```

When I make a new `Cube`, I expected that the `__make_vertices` function I defined in the Cube class would be called, but instead I keep getting the message that the `Shape` classes `__make_vertices` function prints out. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: @Allendar: This is Python, not PHP.

Comment: Sorry I'm falling asleep behind the laptop, hehe, my bad :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references):

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.

In other words, you should only use attribute/method names beginning with two underscores when you specifically *don't* want subclasses to override them, but rather to provide their own private version of them.  This is rare, so usually you won't need to use double-underscore names at all.

Comment: Usually, people associate two leading underscores with *private* members, and one leading underscore with *protected* (or otherwise internal) members. So if you want to allow overriding, use only one underscore at most.

Comment: @poke: That is sort of true, but a lot of reasons people think they want private/protected attributes aren't really valid in Python.  Using single underscores isn't an access control mechanism, it's a documentation convention about which methods can be relied as part of an outward-facing API.  Even using double-underscore methods doesn't prevent access, it just changes the name.  So I shy away from using those terms because they can confuse people into trying to use syntax to get access-hiding abilities that don't really exist in Python.

Comment: A better way to do private methods is not to define the method within the class at all! Instead, have a function in the same package which is passed everything it needs to do the action, i.e. `def _private_foo(obj, arg1, arg2, ...)`.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to mention the convention and the association people usually have with the underscore prefixes :)

Comment: @wheaties I personally would argue that you wouldn’t ever need to (or should) use “private” members ever. Python being dynamic, I can overwrite those at runtime anyway, if I truly desire too. There’s no access protection in Python, so it’s better just accepting that and making the application robust enough to work with that and to document it well enough for people to not misuse it.